# How to retrieve data from localStorage in Next.js 13 middleware?

Tags: next.js, middleware

I am new to Next.js and I'm interested in implementing role-based authentication using Next.js middleware. In my scenario, after a user successfully logs in, I retrieve their role from the database and store it in the localStorage using Redux. To enable role-based routing, I need to access the user's role from the middleware. However, I'm encountering difficulties in accessing the localStorage.

I don't know how can i access the localStorage from nextJS middleware. If you have any suggestions or ideas, please share them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple. You can't. The local storage is part of the users browser (e.g the client). Al middleware runs on the edge, and so does not have access to the users local storage. I recommend using sessions.